# Chrome Extension Popup Questions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm trying to make a bot for a website, to make purchases faster and automated. In order to do so, I am using javascript (atom) and chrome extensions. I need some help with the following things to do with chrome extension popup, which will improve the UI of my program (user interface)

1.Is there a way for the user to set a time for the code to excecute at? For example, a 24 hour clock they can edit using text boxes in the popup. Maybe this triggers a new tab which has a coutdown clock, at the end of which the code is excecuted on the website.

2.Can I create text boxes, so that the user can fill in various details such as item name and size value, that can be integrated with my main javascript code to change which product is purchased by the bot?

3.How do I create dropdown boxes for things like the category, with multiple options. Again, this must correspond with the main JS code.

4.Can I create a login page that must be filled in with a unique login before the user can access the main login page?

5.Can I create little switches?

6.Is there a way for me to customise the buttons with certain fonts, colours and sizes, and to customise the backgroud colour etc. I really want it to pop!

I know that this is a lot of questions, so please feel free to answer one or two rather thatn all of them! I have an incredibly basic understanding of HTML, so I may have some followup questions for you.

Thanks in advance,

Louis

Comment: The popup page is an HTML page, you can do in it (almost) whatever you can in any other webpage, so my answers are: 1. Yes, using `chrome.alarms` API, for example. 2. Yes, HTML `input`. 3. Yes, HTML `select`. 4. Yes. 5. Yes. 6. Yes, using CSS.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I am very much a novice to these things: do you know how I would go about doing any of the above? Thanks again

Comment: You can begin by reading the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview)